# Why my select value has changed but still displayed the old value?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, element-ui

I am learning Vue with Element-UI these days, and I met a problem today early.
I saw my select's value has been changed already on the console, but on the page, it still displayed the old value. Why?
Here's my select tag's code:

```
<el-select v-model="ruleForm.emp" filterable placeholder="please select" @change="empChange">
  <el-option v-for="item in emps" :key="item.id" :label="item.name" :value="item">
  </el-option>
</el-select>
```

Here's the **ruleForm**'s code:

```
ruleForm: {
     emp: {
         id: 1,
         name: '',
         address: ''
     },
     startDate: '',
     position: '',
     positionDetails: ''
}
```

Here's the **empChange** method:

```
empChange(emp){
    this.ruleForm.emp = emp;
}
```

If you need something more to help you to figure out, please let me know and I'll update at once.
Any help will be appreciated!

Update: Vue's and Element-UI's version

```
"element-ui": "^2.4.5",
"vue": "^2.5.2"
```

Update: one emp of the data **emps**:

```
emp: {
id: 1723
name: "test"
address: "address_test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At empChange method, change:

```
empChange(emp){
   this.$set(this.ruleForm, 'emp', emp);
}
```

See [reactivity](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: I changed **empChange** method like this, but still displayed the old value.

Comment: Where are you storing ruleForm? IT seems ok

Comment: And what data is on emps? Maybe the values are not the same to match

Comment: **ruleForm** is stored in vue file's data region. And  one of the **Emps** data is updated in the question, please have a look~